# rx.DOM in rxjs5

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

How can i use Rx.DOM in rxjs5, specially Rx.DOM.jsonpRequest ?

this is a simple implementation, but i wanna use jsonpRequest :

```
function JSONP(url, callbackName) {
  return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
    window.[callbackName] = res => {
      observer.next(res);
      observer.complete();
    };

    let script = document.createElement('script');
    let head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    script.src = url;
    head.appendChild(script);
  }).retry(3);
}
```